# How to get workflow details from Item using Item Web API service

Tags: item-web-api

How Can I get workflow and workflow history for current Item using Sitecore API Item Service?

Get item details using below query

**Query to get Item**

```
/item/{id}/database&language&version&includeStandardTemplateFields&includeMetadata&fields
```

**Json Result**

```
{
          "ItemID": "25a40733-babf-4f16-a025-a3ffb0c84c05",
          "ItemName": "itemName",
          "ItemPath": "/sitecore/content/Home",
          "ParentID": "59b7047e-1063-4f2e-a452-4ca466ecb621",
          "TemplateID": "3191fecf-905e-4ca1-a007-05ba9f5b7455",
          "TemplateName": "templatename",
          "CloneSource": null,
          "ItemLanguage": "en",
          "ItemVersion": "1",
          "DisplayName": "testuser",
          "HasChildren": "True",
 }
```

in the above result don't have the workflow details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to double check but I think you have 2 options here:

1. Set `includeStandardTemplateFields` parameter to `true` (**`includeStandardTemplateFields=true`**):

```
/item/{id}/database&language&version&includeStandardTemplateFields=true&includeMetadata&fields
```

In this case you should get all the fields of the item.

2. Set `fields` parameter to the "," separated fields you want to receive from api (**`fields=__Workflow,__Workflow%20state,__Display_name`**):

```
/item/{id}/database&language&version&includeStandardTemplateFields=true&includeMetadata&fields=__Workflow,__Workflow%20state,__Display_name
```

In this case you will only get the fields from the parameter.

In both scenarios you will not get the full workflow history anyway. I don't think that's possible with Sitecore API Item Service.

I haven't tested it locally but it should do the trick

Comment: thanks, Marek I will try.

Comment: Marek,Yes, I got only workflow state id, workflow id, current workflow state id.I need workflow history

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: "In both scenarios you will not get the full workflow history anyway. I don't think that's possible with Sitecore API Item Service."

Answer (score 0):

It does not return Workflow history, but you can check the current workflow state information. Inclde below querystring to get all possible values from the ItemService API:

`includeStandardTemplateFields=true` (default value is false)

`sitecore/api/ssc/item/87D9ADCB-08CE-4396-86C4-8BAE04D833F7/?database=master&includeStandardTemplateFields=true`

For more detail, you can check the below Sitecore blog/article

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html